# Falling into a weird git rebase/pull loop

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to rebase a feature branch with git.

I switched to the master branch with:

```
git checkout master
```

Got the latest version:

```
git pull
```

Switched back:

```
git checkout iss248
```

Rebased:

```
git rebase master
```

Then for some reason git couldn't fix the conflicts automatically, even though it didn't seem like anything was in conflict: I basically went through all the changes I'd made line by line and approved them.  So then I thought I was done, but

```
git status
```

Said something like:

```
On branch iss248
Your branch and 'origin/iss248' have diverged,
and have 11 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   chalktalk/apps/exams/forms.py
    modified:   chalktalk/apps/lessons/forms.py
```

And in those files there were weird nested conflicts like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
        widget=MyFilteredSelectMultiple('lessons'),
>>>>>>> MyFilteredSelect now takes a content_name parameter
=======
        widget=MyFilteredSelectMultiple('lessons'),
>>>>>>> MyFilteredSelect now takes a content_name parameter
=======
        widget=MyFilteredSelectMultiple('lessons'),
>>>>>>> 18bc77f3387fc6ee6cdf7203a92136c8837b0e73
```

Am I doing something really obvious wrong?

After

```
git rebase master
```

Do I need to follow up somehow to make sure that my local changes are reflected on my github branch?  And why would the rebase not know how to resolve 'conflicts' that were basically just a single line inserted?

Thanks!

Comment: Those nested conflict markers make it appear as if you rebased multiple times without resolving those conflicts first. Also, if you run into conflicts while rebasing, you need to complete the rebase using `git rebase --continue`. You never said you did that, and the “changes to be committed” part in the status also doesn’t suggest that you are still rebasing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolving a merge conflict during a rebase typically consists of three stages:

1. edit the conflicted file(s) to select the proper portions to include and remove the extraneous bits including the conflict markers
2. `git add` the files that were modified, to mark them as no longer in conflict
3. `git rebase --continue` to create the commit and continue with any further commits to be rebased

It appears that at at least one point in the past, you neglected to do either 2 or 3 (or both).

Comment: Yeah I think I must have.  I tried it again, and followed those instructions (before reading this) and it ended up sorted out.  I just was wondering whether I was trying to do something glaringly wrong or just making a mistake.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I did the same but it will goes into infinite loop: (my_child_branch|REBASE 5/10).
It will not going forward. I am stuck in "git rebase --continue".

Answer (score 0):

Just worked my way through this problem, I tried the accepted answer, but kept falling into the loop.

To resolve, I created a branch from a commit prior to the faulty file commit. Then, I pushed the relevant changes to this branch, and merged this branch.

Definitely a workaround and not a holistic solution to the loop, but it got me moving forward.